# Bootstrap 5 Transparent Navbar not working

Tags: navbar, transparent

I'm currently working on a Django project (Practicing) and I was able to make the navbar transparent when I started, and I have implemented quite a fair bit of code since then and have since been unable to make the navbar transparent again, it remains with a white background and the image doesn't show from behind.

[image: example of navbar requiring opacity change]

My goal is to have the image show and navbar links, but no background colour.

Currently my HTML is like this for the navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0" id="navbar-nav2">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" id="linkNavbar" href="#"
            >ABOUT</a
          >
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a
            class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
            href="#"
            id="navbarDropdown"
            role="button"
            data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            PROGRAMS
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="linkNavbar" href="#">GIFTS</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="linkNavbar" href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="linkNavbar" href="#">SHOP</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="linkNavbar" href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And the css that normally would govern the navbar background is:

```
.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0);
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}
```

This worked originally. But now no matter what I do, I have a white background in the navbar, even if i remove 'navbar-light', 'bg-light', remove all other css customisations, ensure all background are a different colour, I still remain with a white background.

I've seen many fixes for this, but none have worked for me.

If anyone could guide me in my mistake,  it'll be greatly appreciated.

Problem:

I've tried customising css and bootstrap default styles but nothing is working to make navbar transparent, remains with white background

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might have a similar issue.

I've found my own solution to the problem I created.

When I had this navbar transparent and working, it was fixed top without the alert being there.

Due to not being fixed-top it was creating its own container section on top of the image it seems.

I reimplemented fixed-top and created a margin from the top to still fit the alert system as so

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">



   .fixed-top { margin-top: 3%; }
```

Customising the fixed-top allowed me to have it transparent and place correctly.

[image: correct navbar]